# Pyserial won't import

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 16:52:21) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import serial

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial'
```

I have tried uninstalling and the reinstalling using:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall pyserial
```

```
sudo pip3 install pyserial
```

```
sudo pip3.7 install pyserial
```

No joy!

Im on a Mac if it matters.

A workaround would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not import pyserial?